# What are the green and red gems beside Github Gist Revisions

Tags: github, gist

I have just started to use Github and have been doing some tests with Gist, I notice beside each revision there are little green and red dots of varying amounts. Does anyone know what they are?

The following image, for example, is captured from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1402136).

[image: Red and green dots.]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those red and green dots represent insertions and deletions in the revision, respectively. There is something similar associated with commits on GitHub (actually, you see the same information when committing in Git), except there you can hover the mouse pointer over the dots and get more information. For example, when hovering over the colored squares in [this commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/d7b59fec39103bdce756f223e8a0267d749bd58d) you can see the number of additions and deletions.

[image]

Comment: Ah makes sense, though they don't seem to be as useful as your example since you can't hover over a gist one. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The hovering behavior is now available in gists. It was added sometime in the last two years.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you know why there is one grey square there as well - and why are there four grey squares in the image that was posted in the question?

Answer (score 0):

green is for highlight the commit ,
red is for deleted lines,
blue is for added lines in different portion