# Git color code for contributor page

Tags: git, github, egit

I was wondering what these colors green and red signify! Also what is this '++' besides green colored number for?

[image]

Thanks,

Before you down-vote this question, please look at this link
[What are the green and red gems beside Github Gist Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328947/what-are-the-green-and-red-gems-beside-github-gist-revisions)  There it looks like green signify for deletion and red for addition!  Although I admit that looks counter-intuitive. Thats why I am asking to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This indicates how many lines of code changed in the commits by this user.

In this case the user has added 2459 and deleted 180 lines of code in 4 commits.

Note: GitHub treats line changes as deletion and addition:

```
- "Orginal Text"
+ "Orginal 2 Text"
```

Would result in `1 ++ / 1--`!

Answer (score 3):

They mean lines added and lines deleted, respectively. The ++ means added; the -- means deleted.

Comment: But if you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328947/what-are-the-green-and-red-gems-beside-github-gist-revisions
Looks like green signify for deletion and red for addition!  Although I admit that looks counter-intuitive. Thanks :-)